# How to resize the clip-path background in a responsive way vertically?

Tags: css, responsive, clip-path

I'm having some troubles to do a responsive background using the css clip-path property. In my case, I have a background in my content container, and this container has more than 100% of the vh. This background has a clipped red bg in a 45º, so when I resize the window, to an intermediate size, the red bg not resize too.

Is there a way to resize a clip-path vertically and horizontally when  I resize the window?

```
.home {
    background-color: $bg-primary-color;
    &::before {
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 87.3rem;
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        background-color: $bg-secondary-color;
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 56.3%);
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 56.3%);

        @include response('tablet') {
            height: 110rem;
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 93%);
            -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 93%);
        }

        @include response('phone') {
            height: 145rem;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you mean you want to always keep 45deg?

Comment: yeah, to talk the truth each page has a different deg, but the idea is maintain the degrees and change the height.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the area of your `clip-path` remain a square shape and its big enough to cover your element.

Here is an example:

```css
.box {
  height:100vh;
  background:url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/1074/1000/1000.jpg) center/cover;
  clip-path:polygon(-100vmax -100vmax,100% -100vmax,100% 100%,-100vmax -50vmax);
  /* change the -50vmax to control the angle*/
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Below an illustration to understand the trick where your element is the red shape and the `clip-path` the black shape

[image]